# Need help to search document with random field names

Tags: mongodb

I looked through the MongoDB documentation and googled this question but couldn't really find a suitable answer.

encounter a problem where I need to search documents in a collection, but 3 fields name will change from one doc to another even though they are always at the same positions.

In the following example, the `366_DAYS` can be `2_HOURS`, `35_DAYs` etc from document to document, but they will be in the same position.

The `_XC4ucB8sEeSybaax341rBg` will change to another random string from doc to doc, again it will be at the same position for all docs.

Other fields do not change name and stay at the same position.

I want a query to search for records where `debitAmount >=creditAmount`  or `endDate > now()`.

```
   set02:PRIMARY> db.account.find({ _id: "53e51b1b0cf22cb159fa5f38" }).pretty()
   {
    "_id" : "53e51b1b0cf22cb159fa5f38",
    "_version" : 6,
    "_transId" : "e3e96377-a2d2-4b75-a946-f621df182c5e-2719",
    "accountBalances" : {
            "TEST_TIME" : {
                    "thresholds" : {

                    },
                    "deprovisioned" : false,
                    "quotas" : {
                            "366_DAYS" : {
                                    "thresholds" : {

                                    },
                                    "quotaCode" : "366_DAYS",
                                    "credits" : {
                                            "_XC4ucB8sEeSybaax341rBg" : {
                                                    "startDate" : ISODate("2014-08-08T18:46:51.351Z"),
                                                    "creditAmount" : "86460",
                                                    "endDate" : ISODate("2014-08-09T18:48:19Z"),
                                                    "started" : true,
                                                    "debits" : {
                                                            "consolidated" : {
                                                                    "creationDate" : ISODate("2014-08-08T19:15:55.396Z"),
                                                                    "debitAmount" : "1300",
                                                                    "debitId" : "consolidated"
                                                            }
                                                    },
                                                    "creditId" : "_XC4ucB8sEeSybaax341rBg"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                    "expiredReservations" : {

                    },
                    "accountBalanceCode" : "TEST_TIME",
                    "reservations" : {

                    }
            }
    },
    "subscriberId" : "53e51b1b0cf22cb159fa5f38"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use arrays for `quotas` and `credits`? That would make the path be the same.

```
"quotas": [
  {
    "days": 365,
    "thresholds": {},
    "credits": [
      {
        "id": "_XC4ucB8sEeSybaax341rBg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Two cases come to mind. Which one applies to you is unclear to me from the question so providing for both possibilities.

**CASE 1:**

You will always have either *366_DAYS, 2_HOURS* or *35_DAYS* inside *quotas* and only one possible *creditId* per document. If this is the case, then why replicate the *quotaCode* and the *creditId* both as a sub-field and as the key inside *quotas* and *credits* respectively. You could alter the structure of your document as follows:

```
{
    "_id": "53e51b1b0cf22cb159fa5f38",
    "_version": 6,
    "_transId": "e3e96377-a2d2-4b75-a946-f621df182c5e-2719",
    "accountBalances": {
        "TEST_TIME": {
            "thresholds": {},
            "deprovisioned": false,
            "quotas": {
                "thresholds": {

                },
                "quotaCode": "366_DAYS",
                "credits": {
                    "startDate": ISODate("2014-08-08T18:46:51.351Z"),
                    "creditAmount": "86460",
                    "endDate": ISODate("2014-08-09T18:48:19Z"),
                    "started": true,
                    "debits": {
                        "consolidated": {
                            "creationDate": ISODate("2014-08-08T19:15:55.396Z"),
                            "debitAmount": "1300",
                            "debitId": "consolidated"
                        }
                    },
                    "creditId": "_XC4ucB8sEeSybaax341rBg"
                }
            },
            "expiredReservations": {

            },
            "accountBalanceCode": "TEST_TIME",
            "reservations": {
            }
        }
    },
    "subscriberId": "53e51b1b0cf22cb159fa5f38"
}
```

Now the *fieldPath* for fields in your queries would be:

```
"accountBalances.TEST_TIME.quotas.credits.creditAmount"
"accountBalances.TEST_TIME.quotas.credits.debits.consolidated.debitAmount"
"accountBalances.TEST_TIME.quotas.credits.startDate"
```

**CASE 2:**

*quotas* and *credits* may contain more than one subdocument. In this case **viktortnk's** approach of having *quotas* and *credits* as arrays will work. The *fieldPath* for your queries may then be written as:

```
"accountBalances.TEST_TIME.quotas.[zero-base-index].credits.[zero-base-index].creditAmount"
"accountBalances.TEST_TIME.quotas.[zero-base-index].credits.[zero-base-index].debits.consolidated.debitAmount"
"accountBalances.TEST_TIME.quotas.[zero-base-index].credits.[zero-base-index].startDate"
```